# sed does not seem to substitute consistently - failure on *

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to write a loop that computes operations in the order they come (not the usual mathematical precedence)
The code goes like this (echo is for debugging):

```
while [[ "$(echo "$newstring"| grep -E ^-?[0-9]+$)" = "" ]]; do
       oldpart="$(echo "$newstring"|cut -f1-3 -d' ')"
       echo "bla $oldpart"
       newpart="$(echo "$oldpart"|bc)"
       echo "ble $newpart"
       newstring="$(echo "$newstring"|sed -e "s/$oldpart/$newpart/")"
       echo "bli $newstring"
done
```

Output is the following when passed $newstring as "6 + 6 * 9":

```
6 + 6 * 9
bla 6 + 6
ble 12
bli 12 * 9
bla 12 * 9
ble 108
bli 12 * 9
bla 12 * 9
ble 108
```

As we can see, 6 + 6 is calculated as 12 as expected, then replaced in the string.
The operation then restarts for 12 * 9, 108 - which fails to replace into the string... and the while never ends

I suspect sed interprets the * which might prevent the desired substition.

Any idea how to bypass that behaviour?

Comment: Yes, `*` is part of basic regular expressions and thus is interpreted. Better to change the approach. Are elements always separated by space in the input expression, or is `1+1` valid? Are only elementary operations supported or should it compute `log(sin(4))`?

Comment: To "compute operations in the order they come" [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) is a natural choice. The tool is `dc`. Your example translates to `echo "6 6 + 9 * p" | dc`

Comment: space can be removed without issues I use them to cut at this moment, the only operations used are + and *. <br> dc approach seemss interesting indeed, but it seems more complicated to automatically generate the calling strings for larger operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using just `bash` with no external commands needed

```
#!/bin/bash
newstring='6 + 6 * 9'

read -a atoms <<<"$newstring"
run=${atoms[0]}               # Initialise running total to the first value

for ((i=1; i<=${#atoms[@]}; i+=2))
do
    op=${atoms[$i]}           # Next operator
    num=${atoms[$((i+1))]}    # Next number
    run=$((run $op num))      # Perform the arithmetic (integer maths)
done
echo "$run"
```

If you want to use floating arithmetic you will need to use either `bc` or `dc`. This variant uses `dc`, as [suggested in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/625077/sed-does-not-seem-to-substitute-consistently-failure-on/625122#comment1169465_625077)

```
#!/bin/bash
newstring='6.5 + 6 * 9'

{
    read -a atoms <<<"$newstring"

    run=${atoms[0]}
    printf "%s " "$run"

    for ((i=1; i<=${#atoms[@]}; i+=2))
    do
        op=${atoms[$i]} num=${atoms[$((i+1))]}
        printf " %s %s" "$num" "$op"
    done
    printf " p\n"
} | dc
```

Comment: Very creative, didn't think about doing it as an array!
I am using the first part thanks a lot